Sublime text weird formatting, misinterpreting data
I have a plain text file that I want to be able to read in Sublime Text. However,
it contains certain strings that are being misinterpreted (I want them to be read as plain text). Here is an example:
100fe000000000000000000                      100000000000000000000                      100000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                                    30  10                                     100000000000000000000

These are being presented as a large very very long white space. (With Word Wrap enabled it looks like pages of white space but all on one line. It is one "character" though because one backspace deletes the whole space.). How do I get Sublime Text to just show me the raw file (that I can get in other editors).

Build 4169




not sure i understand 'as large whitespace' , can you show ?. I've open same data with sublime (same build) and displays as expected

Sorry with a large whitespace I meant many lines of white space. Except it is one character. If I delete one character the whole white space stretching many lines is gone. Yes I have the View/Word Wrap on. Without that it still gets misinterpreted wrongly, now as one very very long empty white line.

@ticktalk, sorry it seems that when I copied the minimal example into the stachexchange question something automatically gets chagned and indeed therefore copying my example does not create the issue (whereas copying what I copied into the stackexchange question space in an empty file does create the issue). I suspect there is a character not supported by StackExchange/Chrome that gets removed by the copy.

@ticktal, Unfortunately I can't share a file directly but here is a temporary link to a file containing hte minimal example https://file.io/DeVRyjQA8sYs.

There's nothing other than plain text in that file - just lots and lots of spaces.  If they're all being deleted by a single backspace, that must be because you have your editor configured to treat spaces as equivalent to a tab - deletion goes back to the previous tab stop.  And I suspect that Sublime Text's "indentation detection" feature is not doing a good job of guessing where the tab stops are supposed to be in this particular file.

... The transfer you requested has been deleted.    is this a MS or Unix platform/file ..

Okay, this question is probably mostly a misunderstanding on my part. There are just a lot of spaces. The fact that backpace/delete removes all of them as one character is apparently just a feature of sublime. There still seems to be a bug with the Word Wrap setting then. It should show all text within the screen without having to scroll to the right (that is what word wrap does). Yet I can't find any non-whitespace character except ] at the start and U at the end.

If I use ctrl-f to search for for example "start" which should be there I indeed find a match but despite the "wrap" setting enabled and examining around the location where it should be according to the highlight in the vertical scroll there is nothing but white space characters there.

New file link: https://fastupload.io/f2e5f19fc0893f5f

What jason says may be correct, the line indenting is probably messing everything up, when combined with the word wrapping feature. As a way test it, you can create a blank file in sublime text, fill it with spaces until the word wrap feature is triggered, and then start typing any text. The problem is reproduced this way. Its probably a bug. If you want a fix, disable word wrap in the view settings.

@CarlHR, ok thanks. I'm probably going to give up on sublime text then. I'm reading logs that have long lines and need word wrap to be readable. But I also need that text isn't  weirdly disappearing just because there are a lot of spaces.
